# Matlab, Straight Line between 2 points with n points between

Tags: matlab, linear-interpolation

I want to make a function that will take 2 data points: `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`.

Then I want to return a function `f`, which is the straight line between the points with `N` points in between.

If I take in the x and y coordinates of the 2 data points then can I do:

```
step_size = (x2 - x1) / N;
range = x1:step_size:x2;
```

and then:

```
f = ((y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1)) * range + ((y1/x1) * ((x2 - x1)/(y2 - y1)));
```

Will this suffice?

Furthermore, I've been searching online and couldn't find any function already out there that does this. But if there is then please advise.

Comment: I think you mean to create a function `[xi, yi] = makeline(x1,y1,x2,y2, N)` right? Or do you really want to create a function that returns a new function?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `linspace`.  For example, define

```
x1 = 0; y1 = 0; x2 = 4; y2 = 4; npoints=6;
```

then

```
[linspace(x(1),y(1),npoints);linspace(x(2),y(2),npoints)]
```

evaluates to:

```
ans =

         0    0.8000    1.6000    2.4000    3.2000    4.0000
         0    0.8000    1.6000    2.4000    3.2000    4.0000
```

That's probably not exactly what you want, but I guess you can figure out the rest.

Furthermore, if you type `edit linspace.m` you can see how the function is implemented should you want to create your own version, one that works on 2-element vectors perhaps.

Comment: I think you mixed up x and y in the linspace call, it makes more sense to me if you have `linspace(x(1),x(2),npoints)` and vice versa for `y`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a function that returns another function to create the line, take a look at [anonymous functions](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html):

```
function fun = makelinefun(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    fun  = @(N) [linspace(x1,x2,N) ; linspace(y1,y2,N)];
end
```

which you use as:

```
f = makelinefun(0,0,6,9);
xy = f(4)

  xy =
      0     2     4     6
      0     3     6     9
```

OR with [multiple output arguments](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2007/01/31/multiple-outputs/):

```
function fun  = makelinefun(x1,y1,x2,y2)
    fun  = @(N) deal(linspace(x1,x2,N), linspace(y1,y2,N));
end
```

which you use as:

```
f = makelinefun(0,0,6,9);
[x,y] = f(4)

  x =
      0     2     4     6
  y =
      0     3     6     9
```